# Request Sign-off in SharePoint Online - business use case

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, content-approval

I have some questions regarding the out of the box request sign-off feature in SharePoint Online.
[image]

- Is it possible to hide a document (for contributors) if sign-off status is not approved ?
- Is it possible to prevent a contributor to manually update the sign-off status ?
- Is it possible to enforce specific approver for a specific document library ? (prevent contributor to send sign-off request to wrong people)

Maybe I'm missing something but from what I understand this only way to do all of this is to use the "old" Submit for Approval feature ? (or build a custom flow)